# Web app performance tracing on Mobile Safari?

Tags: performance, web, mobile-safari, trace

We work on a web application (HTML5 / JS) where performance is critical (physics simulation).

There are a few great options to trace performance on desktops: Chrome Dev Tools timelines, chrome://tracing or the promising [Web Tracing Framework](http://google.github.io/tracing-framework/). The last option seems like the most powerful one. It also supports remote control of Chrome for Android, but unfortunately Mobile Safari is unsupported.

Do you know any other tool that can be used to precisely measure performance on Mobile Safari?

I know [I can debug pages on Mobile Safari with Mac Safari](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/appleapplications/reference/safariwebcontent/DebuggingSafarioniPhoneContent/DebuggingSafarioniPhoneContent.html) and perhaps access timeline and/or profile tools too. Is this the only option? Do you know other interesting ways of performance tracing a webapp on Mobile Safari?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into Weinre a fantastic remote debugging tool based on webkit's developer tools: 
http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/

The timeline tool is still in the early stages but you can create your own timeline events.

Answer (score 0):

For webapp's performance,with enough experience you can tell from the page's debug borders(Compositing Render Layers) and repaint counters,they are not powerful like  Web Tracing Framework does,but in many case they help a lot.Web Tracing Framework already works on android chrome,for mobile safari,mac safari's develop tool also can enable to inspect mobile safari's debug borders and repaint counters,also if you dont got a mac,you can just try [MIHTool](http://www.mihtool.com/) which you can enable debug borders and repaint counters in the app on you iOS device.
Check out [Mobile Web Thursday: Dev Tools](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jXqrgtm-yF8) to learn more about it.